# Assigned properties on file disappear when saved in indexeddb

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I am assigning a custom id and a few other properties to a file object.

```
Object.assign(file,{id: '_abc', customProperty: 'some value'});
```

and then I store the fie in the indexedDb

```
objectStore.put(file,file.id)
```

the file is successfuly stored in the store but the assigned properties are not included in the file in the database whereas the console.log shows all the properties.

**In IndexedDB**

[image: file in indexedDB]

**In Console Log**

[image]

Why the assigned properties are not stored in the db?

The codeSandbox contains a woking example.

[image: Edit indexedDB-Example]

Comment: What is the objectStore that you have used here. Can you please paste the entire code here?

Comment: please show more of your surrounding code. are you sure you are properly waiting to log a message until after the put operation has completed? do you consider yourself knowledgeable about writing asynchronous code or are you still learning it?

Comment: I am creating a working codesandbox to make this clear.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a solution to this problem. I have created a 'CustomFile' object which contais the assigned properties and the orignal file. Now the all the properties of the CustomFile are stored in the indexedDB.

```
const CustomFile = function(file) {
  this.id = idGenerator();
  this.name = file.name;
  this.timestamp = Date.now();
  this.content = file;
};
```